# Mouseover border in a custom control for a textblock

Tags: wpf, xaml, user-controls, textblock

I am trying to create a custom control for a text block that when moused over, a border will appear. I am pretty new to WPF and have only made some very simple custom controls. I need to implement this in a XAML UserControl.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks again, StackOverflow.

EDIT: I am going to have to bind a persistence property to several different controls, so I really need to do this in a custom control. This is what I have, and it isn't working:

```
xmlns:customControls="clr-namespace:****.CustomControls"
....
<customControls:MouseOverBorder>
        <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=HomePageButtonText}"
                   Height="100"
                   Width="100"
                   Margin="5"
                   Text="View Reports" />
</customControls:MouseOverBorder>
```

And the UserControl:

```
<UserControl 
x:Class="****.MouseOverBorder"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
mc:Ignorable="d">

<UserControl.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style x:Key="MouseOverBorder" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1" />
            <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="3" />
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Border.IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="White" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</UserControl.Resources>
<Border Style="{DynamicResource MouseOverBorder}" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="3" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"/>
```

Comment: create a `Style`, with a `Trigger` for `IsMouseOver`. (this doesn't require a custom control, btw)

Answer (score 2):

No need to make a UserControl. I've managed to accomplish this with the following markup:

```
<Border Style="{DynamicResource BorderStyle1}" BorderThickness="1" CornerRadius="3" >
    <TextBlock Text="TextBlock" />
</Border>
```

Here's the style:

```
<Style x:Key="BorderStyle1" TargetType="{x:Type Border}">
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
    <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="3"/>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF123BBA"/>
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

EDIT:

Still don't get it why do you need a UserControl (please don't call it custom control - these are different things), but let's consider your example.

When you write the following

```
<customControls:MouseOverBorder>
    <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=HomePageButtonText}"
               Height="100"
               Width="100"
               Margin="5"
               Text="View Reports" />
</customControls:MouseOverBorder>
```

you are actually setting MouseOverBorder.Content property. Originally it's Content is defined in MouseOverBorder.xaml file. So you are replacing all your UserControl structure with TextBlock. But still I got your idea and have solution for it.

First, add custom DependencyProperty and CLR wrapper for it to MouseOverBorder class:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MyContentTemplateProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("MyContentTemplate", typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(MouseOverBorder), null);

[Browsable(true)]
[Category("Other")]
public DataTemplate MyContentTemplate
{
    get { return (DataTemplate)GetValue(MyContentTemplateProperty); }
    set { SetValue(MyContentTemplateProperty, value); }
}
```

Second, make something inside MouseOverBorder use this property, e.g.

```
<ContentPresenter ContentTemplate="{Binding MyContentTemplate, ElementName=userControl}"/>
<!-- userControl is the Name of MouseOverBorder, defined in xaml -->
```

At last, you can use your UserControl as following:

```
<customControls:MouseOverBorder>
    <customControls:MouseOverBorder.MyContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=HomePageButtonText}"
                       Height="100"
                       Width="100"
                       Margin="5"
                       Text="View Reports" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </customControls:MouseOverBorder.MyContentTemplate>
</customControls:MouseOverBorder>
```